# Mobile check in API with embedded form

Tags: foursquare

I'm looking to pull some information off of the people that check into my location to learn a bit about them. The plan is to offer them a special through foursquare once they've completed the form.  Has anyone done this?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

See https://foursquare.com/business/merchants/claiming for information about claiming your venue and https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/merchants for the relevant API endpoints.